# Array that alphabetizes and alternates between all caps

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to get the user to input five words, which I believe I have. Then the program needs to spit the words in alphabetical order with every other word being in all-caps, starting with the first word, and the remaining words being in all lowercase.

I'm eventually going to have switch the loop to 500 words, and it's only the number in the loop that I need to change. How do I get this to work?

Here's what I have so far:

```
words = []

5.times do
  puts "Please enter a word"
  words << gets.chomp
end

puts words.sort.odd.upcase
```

Comment: Please give us an example of output for input `%w(orange apple lemon melon lime)`. It hard to understand what 'every other word' and 'remaining' mean.

Comment: Can the input words be mixed case? As is, your question is not well defined and leaves too much room for guessing at the requirements.

Comment: Where is `odd` defined? What is its contract?

Answer (score 1):

`with_index` can help you with the *every other word* problem:

```
words = %w(hello world this is test)
# => ["hello", "world", "this", "is", "test"]
words.map(&:downcase).sort.map.with_index {|word, index| index.odd? ? word : word.upcase}
# => ["HELLO", "is", "TEST", "this", "WORLD"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways that don't use indices.

```
arr = %w|the quicK brown dog jumpEd over the lazy fox|
  #=> ["the", "quicK", "brown", "dog", "jumpEd", "over", "the", "lazy", "fox"]
```

Note:

```
arr.sort
  #=> ["brown", "dog", "fox", "jumpEd", "lazy", "over", "quicK", "the", "the"]
```

**#1**

```
e = [:UC, :LC].cycle
arr.sort.map { |w| (e.next == :UC) ? w.upcase : w.downcase }
  # => ["BROWN", "dog", "FOX", "jumped", "LAZY", "over", "QUICK", "the", "THE"]
```

**#2**

```
arr.sort.each_slice(2).flat_map { |u,v| v ? [u.upcase, v.downcase] : [u.upcase] }
  # => ["BROWN", "dog", "FOX", "jumped", "LAZY", "over", "QUICK", "the", "THE"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well (but the question is not so clear) you want to sort and then put one word out of two in uppercase and the other in lowercase:

```
words.sort.each_with_index.map{|w,i| i.odd? ? w.upcase : w.downcase }
```

Test:

```
words=%w( orange banana apple melon)
```

Result:

```
["APPLE", "banana", "MELON", "orange"]
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.

Comment: that a flag for answering the question would be appreciate! ;)

Comment: It's not necessary, or particularly desirable to ask for your answer to be selected. Answer the question to the best of your ability and don't worry about points. Points accumulate with good answers.

Comment: You might want to check your result against your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
arr = %w(orange apple lemon melon lime)
a1, a2 = arr.sort.partition.with_index { |_, i| i.even? }
a1.map(&:downcase).zip(a2.map &:upcase).flatten.compact
```

Comment: Use `flat_map` instead of `map...flatten`

Comment: @theTinMan There is no `map.flatten` in my solution. Or, at least, I do not see, how to do the same with `flat_map`.

Comment: Yeah. I missed that `map` was inside the `zip`. Carry on.

Comment: Mental image: "Aye, aye, sir!" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
user_input = %w(the quick red fox jumped)
uc_flag = true
output = []
user_input.sort.each { |w| 
  output << if uc_flag
              w.upcase
            else
              w.downcase
            end
  uc_flag = !uc_flag
}
output # => ["FOX", "jumped", "QUICK", "red", "THE"]
```

It's old-school but is extremely fast as it only makes one pass through the array.

It can be written a bit more tersely using:

```
output << (uc_flag ? w.upcase : w.downcase)
```

but ternary statements are generally considered to be undesirable.

If the user is allowed to enter mixed-case words, use:

```
sort_by(&:downcase)
```

instead of `sort`.